# HTML Video on Removing and Re-Adding to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, html5-video

I'm using Jquery to remove an element from the DOM temporarily. This element contains an HTML5 video element. Upon re-adding the said element to the DOM. the video is no longer able to play, and the element displays as blank/white, as opposed to displaying the first frame of the video when it was first loaded.

Any explanations as to why this may be? and any suggestions?

Comment: Need to know how you remove the element and how you re-append it. Please show your code.

Comment: I'm actually using a plugin called infinity.js. and I see that it's cloning the elements and removing them. Then, it appends the element using .append()

Comment: If an element is removed with `.remove()` then it becomes useless. If it needs to be re-appended, then remove it with `.detach()` (and keep a reference to it or a jQuery collection containing it).

Comment: i upvoted this because it's actually useful. But I'm still having the same issue :(

Comment: Sounds like you need either to patch `infinity.js.` or find a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried running `.load()` on the video after appending it to the DOM and it worked!